# Vue updates data without waiting for state file to update it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When the page is being loaded for the first time, vue component is not waiting for my custom store file to process it. I thought it might fix it with promises but I am not sure on how to do so on functions that do not really require extra processing time.

I am not including the entire .vue file because I know it surely works just fine. My *store* includes couple of functions and it is worth mentioning it is not set up using vuex but works very similarly. Since I also tested what causes the issue, I am only adding the function that is related and used in `MainComp`.

**Vue component**

```
import store from "./store";

export default {
  name: "MainComp",
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: true,
      storageSetup: store.storage.setupStorage,
      cards: Array,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.storageSetup().then(() => {
      this.cards= store.state.cards;
    });
    this.displayData();
  },
  methods: {
    displayData() {
      this.isLoading = false;
    },
  }
```

**My custom store.js file**

```
const STORAGE = chrome.storage.sync;

const state = {
  cards: []
};

const storage = {
  async setupStorage() {
    await STORAGE.get(['cards'], function (data) {
      if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
        storage.addToStorage('ALL');
      // else case is the one does not work as required
      } else {
        data.cards.forEach((elem) => {
          // modifies the element locally and then appends it to state.cards
          actions.addCard(elem);
        });
      }
    });
  }
};

export default {
  state,
  storage
};
```

Lastly, please ignore the case in setupStorage() when the length of `data` is equal to 0. If there is nothing in Chrome's local space, then a cards is added properly(`state.cards` is an empty array every time the page loads). The problem of displaying the data only occurs when there are existing elements in the browser's storage.

How can I prevent vue from assuming `cards` is not an empty array but instead wait until the the data gets fetched and loaded to `state.cards` (i.e `cards` in `MainComp`)?

Sorry if the problem can be easily solved but I just lost hope of doing it myself. If any more information needs to be provided, please let me know.

Comment: Your `store.js` file doesn't appear to have a default export so you would not be able to have `import store from "./store"`. Also, I definitely would not be assigning the `setupStorage` function as a data property in your component

Comment: Hi there! You're right, it will not work without ```export default``` but it's a mistake I made here and I do have it locally. I edited the question :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue is that `chrome.storage.sync.get` is an asynchronous method but it does not return a promise which makes waiting on it difficult.

Try something like the following

```js
const storage = {
  setupStorage() {
    return new Promise(resolve => { // return a promise
      STORAGE.get(["cards"], data => {
        if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
          this.addToStorage("All")
        } else {
          data.cards.forEach(elem => {
            actions.addCard(elem)
          })
        }
        resolve() // resolve the promise so consumers know it's done
      })
    })
  }
}
```

and in your component...

```js
export default {
  name: "MainComp",
  data: () => ({
    isLoading: true,
    cards: [], // initialise as an array, not the Array constructor
  }),
  async created() {
    await store.storage.setupStorage() // wait for the "get" to complete
    this.cards = store.state.cards
    this.isLoading = false
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Ahh... great! I didn't know I can wait for the cards in the ```MainComponent``` this way. Still long way to master Vue ‍♂️